# How do I change the Salesforce Org that my Marketing Cloud instance is integrated with using Marketing Cloud Connector?

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, production, org

I first integrated my ET/MC instance with a Sandbox salesforce environment. I now want the same instance to integrate with the production environment but can't seem to change the Salesforce Org ID in the 'Salesforce Integration' area of the 'Admin' tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Org Id is an automatic field that ET gets from the credentials of the Tracking User Name (asked just above).

If your tracking User's name is something like name@adress.com.name_of_sandbox, you should change it with a user from your org environment, which would look like a regular email address.

Be aware if you put the exact same email address for you tracking users in both your test and prod environment, you wil have to disable it in the sandbox first.